# sort numbers numerically and strings alphabetically in an array of hashes perl

Tags: perl, sorting, numeric, alphabetical-sort

It's a very easy problem but can't get my way around it. I have an array of hashes. The data structure as follows:

```
my @unsorted = (
    {
        'key_5' => '14.271 text',
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => 'text',
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => '13.271 text',
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => 'etext',
        # ...
    },
);
```

How can I sort the array based on `key_5` of the hash. The string part should be sorted alphabetically. and where the key is `number string` (format is always like this),it should be sorted numerically (ignoring the string part completely). So the output would look like, either:

```
my @sorted = (
    {
        'key_5' => 'etext',
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => 'text',
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => '13.271 text',
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => '14.271 text',
        # ...
    },
);
```

So, the array elements are sorted based on `key_5` of the hash elements.

**Important: Cannot use any perl packages that are not shipped with native perl installation. Using perl 5.18**

Comment: Unless this is a homework assignment (in which case you shouldn't be asking for our help anyhow), you absolutely can use functions from non-core modules. You can use `local::lib` and install it to your home directory (or equivalent). You can put the module into a `lib/` subdirectory of your project and use it from there. Worst case, as long as it's a pure-Perl module (which Sort::Key::Natural is), you can copy/paste the relevant code directly into your program.  (And S::K::N is only 104 lines long, so you could even copy the whole module into your source file if you wanted to.)

Comment: @DaveSherohman First of all it's not a homework assignment. Secondly, I am not allowed to install any library that will be used for production. I understand that it's merely just a copy paste but while doing so I will violating rules of the institution. So my hands are tied to the already installed modules.

Comment: @DaveSherohman: I don't think `Sort::Key::Natural` is pure Perl because I see `Key.xs`.  But, it looks like `Sort::Naturally` might be, and it might be suitable.

Comment: @toolic - Fair point.  I only looked at the source of S::K::N itself and forgot to also check its dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Sort::Key::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural):

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natkeysort );

my @sorted = natkeysort { $_->{key_5} } @unsorted;
```

The above produces the following from your input:

```
[
    {
        'key_5' => '13.271 text'
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => '14.271 text'
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => 'etext'
        # ...
    },
    {
        'key_5' => 'text'
        # ...
    },
]
```

If that's not good enough, you can use the following:

```
use Sort::Key::Multi qw( unskeysort );   # uns = (u)nsigned int, (n)umber, (s)tring

my @sorted =
   unskeysort {
      $_->{key_5} =~ /^([0-9.]+)\s+(.*)/s
         ? ( 1, $1, $2 )
         : ( 0, 0, $_->{key_5} )
   }
      @unsorted;
```

Comment: well.. that a bummer, I can't use packages that does not come with native perl installation. I will update my question. sorry about that.

Comment: This should be easy to adapt to `sort`, especially if you use it as part of a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: could you please guide me or give me a hint on how to adapt it with sort. Then I can give it a try. I already achieved the task at hand by changing my data structure but I am keen to solve the challenge.

Comment: I did. I linked to a doc that explains